# MAX date/time for each instance

Tags: sql, max

Good morning:
I have this query but I need it to give me the last date/time for each order. Orders are sometimes worked on multiple times each date...I only want the last instance. Here is the query...any help would really be appreciated...thanks in advance

```
SELECT      dbo.fn_GetNotesForOrder(o.orderid) as Notes, o.OrderNumber, ss.statusname, max(oh.EntryDate),  l.locationcode, l.locationname, a.street, a.city, a.province, a.postalcode, oh.UserID

FROM         orders as o
                               INNER JOIN
             OrderHistory as oh on o.OrderID = oh.OrderID
                               INNER JOIN 
             Statuses as ss on ss.StatusID = oh.Status
                               INNER JOIN   
             addresses as a on a.addressid = oh.addressid
                               INNER JOIN
             locations as l on l.locationid = a.locationid

             WHERE     (oh.EntryDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-06-24 00:00:00', 102) AND oh.EntryDate < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-06-29 00:00:00', 102)) AND 
                      (UserID in ('MAXWELLPAPER\leyre'/*, 'MAXWELLPAPER\ndwyer', 'MAXWELLPAPER\jploeger', 'MAXWELLPAPER\jpquintanilla', 'MAXWELLPAPER\dwatkinson'*/))

             group by o.orderid, o.ordernumber, ss.statusname, l.locationname, l.locationcode, a.street, a.city, a.province, a.postalcode, oh.UserID, oh.entrydate
             order by oh.entrydate
```

Comment: Anyone? Tombom, I do not see the added characters...Thanks...

Comment: You can use RANK() or ROW_NUMBER() or a subquery